# matching the tense of two verbs in one sentence

Tags: tense

> "What you gave me is really interesting."

When I say this kind of sentence, what I want to say is like below.

> "I have one object. And it was given to me from you in the past. Now, I think it is really interesting."

That's why I use the past tense in the first verb 'give' and the present tense in the second verb 'be'.

But the textbooks in my country say that it is wrong because I use different tenses in one sentence. So is it really wrong? If it is, is there any way that I can describe two different time point in one sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "What you gave me is really interesting."

sounds perfectly fine to me - I think your textbook is wrong. I guess your textbook simply means to be consistent with tenses - something like "she opened the front door and walks into the house" would be wrong.